# How to enable several remote developers to share one InstallShield station?

Tags: project-management, service, installshield

Several developers need to use InstallShield to build and test their code,
but we have only a single-station InstallShield license.
We need an idea, a legal way to enable each developer to build his installation from his workstation, as part of an Ant script run, whenever he wants.
Perhaps run IS through some kind of a service, that manages a queue of remote requests?
Assume it takes Installshield about 30 seconds to build an installation.
Edit: we use CruiseControl for CI, but we want to enable a developer to build a test installation **before** committing his changes to SVN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default InstallShield is licensed for a single user on a single machine, so sharing it in any way is not allowed. There are some options however:

If these users don't need to use the Installshield IDE but only want to re-build existing setup projects with the latest application files, you could use the Stand-Alone Build engine (SAB). This is a command line tool, intended for build servers for automated nightly builds. Depending on the version and edition of Installshield you have, you may already own a number on SAB licenses (Installshield 2011 Premier includes 5, 2011 Professional includes 1, additional SAB licenses can be purchased separately).

If you have several developers who need to use the Installshield IDE from time to time, a floating ("concurrent") license may work for you. They are more expensive than the standard, node-locked licenses. But you get more flexibility and can save in the long term (less maintenance renewal costs), compared to the cost of one node-locked license per user.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think each developer can use InstallShield on his own computer without using an extra license. You have to use it on a central server somewhere. My suggestion would be to use a build system like [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) or [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) to pull the latest code from your source control, build it, and package it up as an MSI. It is actually a best practice in the industry to have a continuous integration build server building everything (and running unit tests) as often as possible. A handy side effect of this is that an extra license is not consumed.

Comment: Thanks. We do use CruiseControl for CI, but we want to enable a developer to build a test installation before committing his changes to SVN. Besides, we would like to use InstallShield from three different machines running CruiseControl.